# objective-c : iphone programming : Showing variables on UIAlert view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uialertview

i want simply to show a double value on a uialert view it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you showing the `UIAlertView` now?  Something like the following should work:

```
double myDouble = 12.6;
NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", myDouble];
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertString
                                                  message:nil
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[myAlert show];
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the value into a formatted `NSString` and send that to the alertView:

```
NSString *messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:"@number = %.2f", 42.0];


UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title text" message:messageString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```